# language overrides explanation

Tags: magento-1.8, overrides, language

say i want to change my language of gift options to gift message.
i have a translate.csv file in my package/theme/locale/
it doesnt overwrite it.
so i found the language file in app/locale/Mage_giftmessage.csv

but isnt this a core file? I just need some clarification. 
some translations work from my translate.csv and some dont. why is that?
will a change to the app/locale/* files get overwritten on an update or are they also override files? if they do get overwritten how do i override these files properly?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Magento comes with translation files for language `en_US`, which means, that you have to download separately the translations for other languages. This means, that your translations (other than `en_US`) won't be overwritten unless you overwrite them manually.
You can also specify your own translation csv in your module's `config.xml` something like this:

```
<adminhtml>
    <translate>
        <modules>
            <Your_Module>
                <files>
                    <default>Your_Translation.csv</default>
                </files>
            </Your_Module>
        </modules>
    </translate>
</adminhtml>
```

Then just create `Your_Translation.csv` in `/app/locale/[language code]/`. And then you will be able to use it like:

`Mage::helper("your_module_helper")->__("some text to translate")`

Comment: so i would create a copy of en_US in app/locale/ called something like en_MYJOB and then do i assign that in the system cofiguration?

Comment: I would rather specify my own translate csv. But you can also specify other language in System configuration -> General -> Locale Options -> Locale, and name your folder as what the selected option's value is. (So en_MYJOB won't work, but en_GB will)